# JQuery ajax and promise chaining order

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

In my situation I have a jQuery AJAX call and an optional `then`:

```js
var ajax = $.get({ /* params */ }).done(function(request) {
  // success handling. no explicit return, so return undefined
}).fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
  // faliure handling. no explicit return, so return undefined
});

if (_needFinalization) {
  ajax.then(function() {
    // finalization handling. no explicit return so return undefined
  });
}
```

It is not clear to me how to do the promise chaining. I have read something about the fact that returning nothing is a bad practice, so I am concerned about my `undefined` approach.

My goal was to execute the AJAX call first, execute `success` or `fail` (as the second step) and optionally as the last step execute the finalization function inside the `then`.

Comment: What you write depends entirely on whether the `if (_needFinalization)` test needs to be performed at the time when the promise chain is built or when it settles. The code, in the two cases, will be very different.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 i need to decide how to build the promise chain, for that reason i put the if in that moment. Assuming that _needFinalization is true i would also be certain that the finalization logic is the last executed.
I have discovered that placing an .always() as last promise give me that guarantees

Comment: OK, maybe I misunderstood the question but `.always()` doesn't in itself address your requirement to perform a test in the promise building phase.

Comment: Another issue is that jQuery's `.done()` and `.fail()` don't form a proper Promise chain as their returned values / throws are not propagated down the chain. For that reason, never use those methods; use `.then()` and `.catch()` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use .always method to execute the finalization function.

> jqXHR.always(function( data|jqXHR, textStatus, jqXHR|errorThrown ) { }); (added in jQuery 1.6)
>
> An alternative construct to the complete callback option, the .always() method replaces the deprecated .complete() method.

You can see it working here:

```js
function log(content){
   console.log(content);
}

var newPromise = $.Deferred();

$.when(newPromise).done(function() {
    log("When");
});

newPromise.then(function() {
    log("Then");
}).done(function() {
    log("Done");
}).fail(function() {
    log("Fail");
}).always(function() {
    log("Always");
});
newPromise.resolve();
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Promise callbacks — .done(), .fail(), .always(), and .then() — are invoked, in the order they are registered. So you should register `always()` after `done()` and `fail()` to execute the finalization function at the end.

Comment: so if i does not missunderstood anything my then clause is executed prior than ajax call complention.

Comment: promise callbacks — .done(), .fail(), .always(), and .then() — are invoked, in the order they are registered. Let me update the answer. Just register the `always` after `done` and `fail`.